# Reactive systems - Why do we need back pressure if everything is communicating via TCP

Tags: sockets, tcp, system.reactive

Maybe I haven't understood what back pressure is trying to solve, but let's say in a microservice architecture where everything is communicating via HTTP (which is backed by TCP of course). Back pressure exists so that no service gets loaded with requests more than what it can process. Now if a service is busy processing requests, won't this be propagated back to the underlying TCP connection where the HTTP requests are being read (i.e. the process won't 'read' from the underlying socket it is listening on?

Comment: I'm not sure what this "back pressure" is. But anyway there's one more layer before a process: kernel. Requests get buffered there before reaching a process. Not sure if it's helpful.

Comment: That's the new jargon used in Reactive systems! i.e. in a producer-consumer pattern, if a consumer is slow, then this information is propagated to the producer (back pressured) so that producer slows down and the whole system is in harmony @freakish

Comment: TCP unable to read on the socket is probably too late, and the system is already degraded. Moreover, it does not stop the clients from sends tons of traffic.